# Learn Umbraco without any .net knowledge

Tags: asp.net, .net, content-management-system, umbraco

I am starting to develop website using Umbraco CMS.Currently I only concentrated on programming HTML JavaScript and CSS for websites.
After do researching and read few Umbraco sites, can I develop a Umbraco site without any .net knowledge?
Is there any best tutorial books and videos i can start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I develop a Umbraco site without any .net knowledge?

Yes, you can. If you are mostly focused on static content. You will need .net knowledge when you add dynamic content to the umbraco site. This is accomplished through the use of macros.

I'd advice you to try the pay-as-you-go subscription to Umbraco TV. It's 19 euros a month, and they have more than 150 in-depth video tutorials that will help you get started on using .net with Umbraco.